# Struct initialisation with function pointer

Tags: c++, syntax, function-pointers

I found the following C++ code with syntax I have never before seen. Does anybody care to elaborate how this workss?

**Function 1**

```
glm::vec3 BottomCircleOffset(float fElapsedTime)
{
    return glm::vec3(.0f,.0f,.0f);
}
```

**Function 2**

```
glm::vec3 OvalOffset(float fElapsedTime)
{
    return glm::vec3(.1f, .1f, .1f);
}
```

**Instance Struct**

```
struct Instance
{
    typedef glm::vec3(*OffsetFunc)(float);

    OffsetFunc CalcOffset;

    glm::mat4 ConstructMatrix(float fElapsedTime)
    {
        glm::mat4 theMat(1.0f);
        theMat[3] = glm::vec4(CalcOffset(fElapsedTime), 1.0f);
        return theMat;
    }
};
```

Until now this is all fine. I understand *OffsetFunc* is a typedef for a function pointer taking a float as argument and returning a glm::vec3. I also understand CalcOffset is a variable to such a function.

The code then goes to create an array of Instance types like so:

```
Instance g_instanceList[] =
{
    {StationaryOffset},
    {OvalOffset},
    {BottomCircleOffset},
};
```

This is syntax I have never come across before:

- How are we initialising an Instance type by simply putting the name of a function?
- The Instance struct not even having a constructor which takes a function pointer, how does it know to initialise *CalcOffset* to this value?

Comment: the name of a function is a pointer to that function.

Comment: This is [*aggregate initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Look it up.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: No, it isn't. It _converts_ to one. This matters, because a function may be overloaded, and then one name can convert to two or more distinct pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Instance` is an *aggregate* - it contains public data members, but no constructors, destructors or other complications, so can (in many ways) be treated like a `struct` in C.

In particular, it can be *aggregate-initialised*, by specifying a list of values for the members enclosed in braces. A simple example:

```
struct s {int a,b,c;};
s example = {1,2,3};    // initialises a=1, b=2, c=3
```

Arrays can also be aggregate-initialised:

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
```

and, if the array members are aggregates, then each of them can be aggregate-initialised in turn:

```
s a[3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

Your example is the same as this: each `Instance` in the array is aggregate-initialised, using the provided function pointer to initialise the `CalcOffset` member.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regular C-style initialization of a `struct`. Recall that you can initialize an array of `struct`s like this:

```
struct x {
    int a;
};
x data[] = {{1}, {2}, {3}};
```

Your code uses the same syntax, but with a function pointer in place of an `int`.